# Как удалить строки в CSV файле где встречаются дубликаты в определенном столбце?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

Есть файл, в котором есть дубли по первому столбцу. Как при помощи `pandas` удалить дубли?

```
собака, 33
барсук, 43
заяц, 98
волк, 86
собака, 46
енот, 36
заяц, 82
```

Лишними тут будут слова в первом столбце:

> собака, заяц

Мне нужно в результате сохранить список уникальных по первому столбцу строк в csv-файл:

```python
собака, 33
барсук, 43
заяц, 98
волк, 86
енот, 36
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [DataFrame.drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\download\data.csv', header=None, 
                 names=['name','val'], sep=',\s*',
                 engine='python', encoding='utf-8')
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['name']).to_csv(r'c:\download\res.csv', header=None, index=False)
```

результат:

```
собака,33
барсук,43
заяц,98
волк,86
енот,36
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку!
У меня есть ошибка, подскажете как её решить?

ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
  names=['name', 'val'], sep=',\s*', encoding='utf-8')

Comment: @Mavar, это не ошибка, это предупреждение. Используйте параметр `engine='python'`, чтобы избавиться от предупреждения

Comment: @Mavar, кстати, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, [проголосуйте за ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) и/или [отметьте его как решение](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)